# What is the difference between java.util.logger.setLevel() and handler.setLevel()?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I'm using java.util.Logger in my project and I'm using a simple ConsoleHandler. By default the logging level was 'Info'. I wanted to change the level to 'Fine'. But, I had to change level on both Logger and Handler. Why? What is the need for this? Why was it designed this way? Why can't I set the level on Logger/Handler alone and be done with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Logger` can own multiple `Handlers`. E.g. a logger might have a `ConsoleHandler` and a `FileHandler` to which it will forward a log event simultaneously.

A `Logger` and a `Handler` can have different log level settings for filter purpose.

- `Logger.setLevel()` will configure your logger to only log from a
  certain level.
- `Handler.setLevel()` will configure your handler to
  only handle log events from a logger from a certain level.

This way you can set up your logger with `Logger.setLevel(INFO)` to log pretty much everything.
In addition you can tell you `FileHandler`, which is attached to your "Info" logger to only handle logs which are at least a warning `FileHandler.setLevel(WARNING)`. You `ConsoleHandler` will still show you Info logs, where as in you log file you'll only find warnings and errors.

Try it out. It's very simple.